Connecting Grafana to local Prometheus and to multiple remote Prometheus instances on separate servers
Current Setup:
I have multiple individual Kubernetes Clusters of the following setup:
1:1:1 of Kubernetes Cluster : Grafana : Prometheus
Central cluster also requires its own Prometheus. It is the same as the other clusters, but needs to have the additional responsibility of allowing querying of the data from other clusters.

What I'm trying to do:
We are trying to use one of the clusters as a Central Monitoring solution for the other globally distributed clusters.
I know Grafana can be connected to multiple Prometheus and I need some advice on how to connect the central Grafana to the remote instances.
The image is my current idea of how this will work (directly connecting central grafana to remote prometheus) but I don't know if I need to have an individual Prometheus on the central cluster for each site cluster if I want to use something like remote-write? Or is there a way to connect Central Cluster Grafana to each remote Prometheus instance directly? Is there a better option I don't know about?
I've also considered federation but I have no idea how that would work when the site clusters are distributed across the globe and there doesn't seem to be a way to expose prometheus via public ip easily. If that's my best solution then I need advice on how to find the relevant public uri for the target.
Also please note that the central prometheus in the image is connected to the grafana instead of prometheus mainly just as a way of saying connecting central clusters to site clusters. So treat it like cluster -> cluster connection rather than connecting specific containers.
Issues
These are production clusters so I can't destroy and restructure anything entirely. This has to be a form of an upgrade. Or if a full restructure is necessary then that has to be the last resort.
I can't rely on trial and error unfortunately and can't make an attempt with a less than ideal solution that will eventually cause problems down the line which is why I'm trying to find the optimal solution from experts rather than just go with my best guess.
Concluding thoughts
Looking for advice on best way to achieve this. I am not an expert in Grafana or Prometheus so if I'm thinking about this completely wrong I'm happy for any advice that I can receive.
If stackoverflow isn't appropriate for this question please let me know where a better place for the question is and I will migrate my post there. Thanks in advance.
